# Latest fink unable to install xemacs on High Sierra

Tags: high-sierra, emacs, x11, fink

I did a fresh install of fink 0.43.1 on a High Sierra system, then installed `texlive` and all of its prerequisites. That all works fine.

Then I try to add `xemacs`:

`fink install xemacs`

and I am met with this error:

```
Information about 10475 packages read in 1 seconds.
Can't resolve dependency "system-xfree86 (>= 3:2.7.112-3)" for package "xemacs-21.4.22-9" (no matching packages/versions
found)
Exiting with failure.
```

The `fink list` command indicates the latest available version of `system-xfree86` is `2.7.86-3`. How can I get around this?

Comment: Do you have Xquarts installed?

Comment: Yes, it is under /opt/X11, which I believe is the standard location (I am fairly new to X on OS X).

Comment: Where was x quartz installed from?

Comment: Does *fink* know it's there, or did you install it from the separately-downloadable Xquartz?  Having said that, it looks like your problem is simply that fink does not currently have a version of XFree86 that satisfies the dependency introduced by the Xemacs maintainer.  I’d have to ask why you're trying to install an Emacs that's going to depend on X11 being running... not at all getting into why run GNU Emacs vs Xemacs, but the X11 dep would normally be a hard stop these days on a Mac.

Comment: Haven't used `fink` for ages, but isn't there an Emacs which doesn't require X11?

Comment: http://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/browse.php?name=emacs&sec=editors seems to indicate there are some

Comment: Thanks for the comments, all. Unfortunately, the customer in question has **required** xemacs, so that decision is out of my hands. I assumed (perhaps naively) that the xemacs build process would use whatever X was installed via fink. But that is why I am getting the error message - fink xemacs requires xfree86 2.7.112-3 or later, but fink only provides xfree86 2.7.86-3. Rather than mucking about with a fink package, perhaps I can just build xemacs from a source tarball. Thoughts?